# Android Market - Time to wait between two updates

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to know how many times I must wait to post an update for my application. I want to be sure that the update will appears in the "news" section of the Android Market.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to game the Market system. Don't do that. Update your app when it needs updating, i.e. when you have new features or bug-fixes.

In my experience, updating too often will make existing users angry, and you'll get several one-star "too many updates - uninstalled" comments. I think those are a bit dumb (I'm always glad to have well-maintained apps), but the bottom line is still - don't update if you don't have to.

You can update several times a day if you wish, there's no limitation regarding that. Personally, I tried to wait at least 14 days inbetween updates, but if I can hold out even longer, I will.

Comment: 98% of users are dumb like hell.  There will be low-star ratings no matter what you do.  As for the frequency of updates - I also try to not update too often, but if there's an important bugfix I'll try to post it ASAP.  Nowadays when apps can be updated automatically it's not that much of a hassle anymore for the users if there're frequent updates.

Answer (score 3):

Updates are an hidden question to the user, "Do I really need this app?"
There are two buttons: Update and Uninstall.
Easy enough to press the Uninstall-Button.
So, with every update you will loose installations ...

S.

Answer (score 0):

My experience: less than 2 weeks but I think also, that you have to change the description more than just a bit. I cant believe that the Market only check for "waiting time".

Answer (score 0):

I always thought it was 7 Days.

Answer (score -1):

You can update as many times you wish on Android Market Place. Normally, I try to update my app on NET-30 day basis. Reason being that for any new update, Google marks it as new app and try to **promote the updated app in marketplace**.
 Most importantly, the app is given a **position** in **New Chart** and that helps **boost** your **download**. 
On the other side, if you  update often, you may annoy your users and they may leave bad comments if they don't see much change in UI and any extra feature being added.
 It's wise to update your app once every 2-3 weeks.

Comment: what do you mean by `app is given a position in New Chart`?